# How to handle keyboard shortcut in TrackPopupMenuEx

Tags: c, winapi

I creted a pop up menu where I used **drawtext** function (owner drawn menu ) to put underline bellow few menu items . I used  like **Save &Page As...**

Design is like the following
[image]

The intent to put underscore bellow p of "Save Page As..." was that user can press P intead of clicking .
When i called [**trackpopupmenuex**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenuex) the code is waiting for my inputs . Instead of clicking I press p.  Where am i required to handle the shortcut key or i should say user keyboard input  ?

Comment: The function doesn't care if you press a key or click the item with the mouse.  Either way, a WM_COMMAND message is sent to the hwnd window to tell you about it.  It is often handy to include the TPM_RETURNCMD flag in the fuFlags argument, the return value of the function then tells you which item was activated.

Comment: No message is recieved by me . Trackpopupmenu is handling that internally i guess and hence my doubt on where to handle this logic that pressing p means "save page as" menu item

Comment: You can use the ampersand prefix in the text of menu item, eg `Save &Page As...`. The ampersand prefix is processed in the menu handling code, by uderscorring the next letter and generating the `WM_COMMAND` message when the key with assiociated letter is pressed.

Comment: i used that in InsertMenuItem and appendMenuItem . It handles the code but does not show underscore and keeps &  .